# WPF Show/Hide a set of controls

Tags: wpf

I'm working on a WPF desktop application. The MainWindow is a maximized window that has a menu with few menu items. I would like to display few controls within a groupbox on the center of the window. This groupbox contains controls depending on the menu item clicked. So the size of the groupbox should not be static. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your XAML like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Click"  Height="30" Width="160"/>
            <Button Content="Click"  Height="30" Width="160"/>
            <!--<Button Content="Click"  Height="30" Width="160"/>-->
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>        
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock  FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="MainUserWork Panel"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```